# Rcpp still cannot get built

Tags: r, rcpp

Even after the latest fixes in Rcpp when I rebuild the package I get the message below. This is when I try to deploy to a client's machine, it works fine on  mine.

```
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'Rcpp', details:
    call: new_dummyObject(.dummyInstancePointer)
    error: object 'class__dummyInstance' not found
Error: package or namespace load failed for 'Rcpp'
```

Any ideas of what is going wrong?

Comment: There was one comment on the rcpp-devel relating this to Windows 2008 server and permissions -- maybe that is clue. Otherwise, this *works for everybody else* including win-builder and CRAN, so as nobody can replicate your issue fixes may be hard to come by.